# Nextflow: How to initialize channel from CSV file but only after CSV file created?

Tags: nextflow, workflow-management

Process A runs a python script which generates a CSV file in some absolute file path say "/mnt/x/blah.csv".

Process B needs to consume the CSV file line by line, after process A has finished.

The trouble is that the channel to input to B is initialized at the beginning before "/mnt/x/blah.csv" is created by A so it fails. This occurs even if I collect the result of process A as input to process B (because channel is initialized regardless)

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2


def get_the_csv_records() {
    Channel
        .fromPath("/mnt/x/blah.csv")
        .splitCsv(header:true, quote: '\"')
        .map{ it.TheFieldIWant }
}

process process_a() {
    
    output:
    val("I'm done!")

    '''
    python.exe ./make_the_csv_file.py --path=/mnt/x/blah.csv
    '''
}

process process_b() {

    input:
    val(previous_step_is_done_dummy_variable)
    val(the_field)

    '''
    echo ${the_field}
    '''

}

workflow do_a_then_b{
    process_a()
    process_b(process_a.out.collect(), get_the_csv_records())
}
```

This fails immediately with "No such file: /mnt/x/blah.csv" because the channel is initialized before process_a has even started.

Same behavior occurs when using concat:

```
    process_b(process_a.out.collect().concat(get_the_csv_records()))
```

Question:

1. How can I make process_b() only read the input channel from the CSV file after it is created?
2. Alternatively, can I make process_b() trigger when process_a() is finished some other way?
3. Alternatively, can I add an intermediate step which reads process_a.out.collect(), then reads /mnt/x/blah.csv and outputs it into some existing channel which process_b() takes as input?
4. Another approach - what is the way to create a channel which outputs the results of splitCsv, when the file is not known at compile time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using latest version of Nextflow which support the DSL 2 language, and assuming your python process output the file blah.csv, then the easiest way to move forward will be:

```
process process_a() {
    output:
    path("blah.csv")

    '''
    python.exe ./make_the_csv_file.py --path=blah.csv
    '''
}

process process_b() {

    input:
    val(the_field)

    '''
    echo ${the_field}
    '''

}

workflow do_a_then_b{
    process_a() \
        | splitCsv \
        | map{ it -> it.TheFieldIWant } \
        | process_b
}
```

You can also refer to the nextflow google group.